# Percentile vs Percentile rank

Tags: quantiles, frequentist, percentage

I have the read [the definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) many times and I still don't quite understand the difference.

[This article](http://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Ewooland/hm2ed/Part3Module1/prVsNth.html) says:

> A statement such as:
>
> "*A score of 600 has a percentile rank of 80*"
>
> has a different meaning from a statement such as
>
> "*The 80th percentile is 600*"

Why is the meaning different?  What would be an easy concise example that shows the difference?

Comment: The very next statement in that article answers your question with "The first of these two statements says that 80% of the population had scores that were less than 600, while the second statement says that 80 percent of the population had scores of 600 or less."

Comment: Thanks @whuber, so is it really just a `<` vs `<=` difference?

Comment: A pretty detailed explanation was added to the referenced [wikipedia page for "percentile"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Percentile&oldid=1114275310) after this question was asked. See the third paragraph from the top.