# Finding percentile rank of a data value

Tags: self-study, quantiles

Can someone please help me with the following question?

> Find the percentile rank of $82$ from the following data set: $53, 68,69,70,70,70,75,76,77,80,82,82,85,85,85,88,92,93,96,100$

My work:

There are $20$ data values and $10$ data values below the first $82$. Then the percentile rank is $50$. However, the textbook answer key says $60$. What did I do wrong? If I did the second $82$, the percentile rank is then $55$, still not $60$...

Comment: @Henry Sorry about that, there was a missing third $85$! I fixed it.

Comment: Please consult your definition of "percentile rank" and pay attention to the details.  In particular, should you be counting values less than 82 or should you be counting values *less than or equal to* 82?

Comment: @whuber Oh! It must be less than or equal to! Thanks so much for taking the time to explain to me, and I apologize for my beginner mindset!!

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/164881

Comment: @whuber Do you know of a reliable online source that has a proper definition of percentile rank? I've seen different formulas, e.g. compare [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Percentile_rank&oldid=1136815121), [fu-berlin](https://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/en/v/soga/Basics-of-statistics/Descriptive-Statistics/Measures-of-Position/Percentiles-and-Percentile-Rank/index.html), and [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#percentrank).

Comment: The [latter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#percentrank) explicitly mentions "percentile rank," but perhaps that is a mistake, as the [underlying implementations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-window.html) refer to "relative rank".

Comment: @djvg I don't rely on supposing there is some universal definition, because definitions vary (especially concerning (a) whether to rank values in ascending or descending order; (b) whether to use inequality or strict inequality; and (c) how to convert ranks into percentiles -- *e.g.*, do they range from 0 to 100 or from 100/(n+1) to 100n/(n+1)?).  Instead, I start by seeking a definition by the source I am consulting or reverse-engineering the definition from the source's examples.